# How do you theme the taxonomy description field?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, theming

I need to theme the `description` field on a taxonomy page. I've tried `field--description.tpl.php` with no success.

Also, do I also copy the contents of `/modules/field/field.tpl.php` as a default template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term description isn't a field, it's actually a property of the taxonomy term entity and doesn't have a theme/template associated with it.

It's built up in [`taxonomy_term_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_view/7) as a standard render array:

```
$build['description'] = array(
  '#markup' => check_markup($term->description, $term->format, '', TRUE),
  '#weight' => 0,
  '#prefix' => '<div class="taxonomy-term-description">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

So to theme it you could write a preprocess function for the taxonomy term template, maybe something like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['content']['description'])) {
    $vars['content']['description']['#prefix'] = '<div class="my-class">';
    $vars['content']['description']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha, I knew it!! Great answer!

Comment: Just a note - that this overwrites the current #prefix and #suffix wrappers.